# See More in DataSheet View?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, view, datasheet

This seems like a simple enough question although I can't seem to find the answer on Google or here thus far:

Are you able to change the page when in Datasheet View - SharePoint 2010?

I also attempted to make my view item limit more (500) so I could potentially see more in Datasheet view, but still only the default 80 or so...

Does anyone have any insight on this?  It would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Data sheet view" does not handle pages. You will see all items according to the criteria specified in the filter view settings. If you want to see all the items, be sure that there is no filter criteria specified in that configuration.

Comment: Thank you @jpussacq I really didn't do my homework on this one, but I still really appreciate the answer!